# Locally conformal Kahler manifolds with SU(4) structure

Tags: ag.algebraic-geometry, dg.differential-geometry

I would like to know if there exist eight-dimensional manifolds such that:

- It has SU(4)-structure.
- It is locally conformal Kahler.
- It is not a Calabi-Yau four-fold.

A weaker question that also interests me is if there exist an eight-dimensional manifold such that:

- It is spin
- It is locally conformal Kahler.
- It is not a Calabi-Yau four-fold.

Finally, a related question would be:

- Are all spin manifolds simply connected?

Thanks.

Comment: Every closed orientable surface is spinnable, but most of them aren't simply connected. For examples in higher dimensions you can take products of these.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Here's an example:  $M^8 = S^1\times S^7$.

This manifold is parallelizable, so it has an $\mathrm{SU}(4)$-structure.

It is diffeomorphic to the quotient of $\mathbb{C}^4\setminus\{0\}$ divided by the $\mathbb{Z}$-action generated by $z\mapsto 2z$, which preserves the standard Kähler structure up to a constant multiple, so it is locally conformally Kähler.

It is not a Kähler manifold, so it can't be Calabi-Yau, since it is compact and has vanishing second deRham cohomology group.

Because it is parallelizable, it is spinnable, but it is not simply connected.

Comment: Thank you very much. I don't fully understand

"...which preserves the standard Kähler structure up to a constant multiple..."

Wouldn't this mean that it is globally conformaly Kahler?

Comment: @S.S.:  I'm not sure how to answer this.  The Kähler structure on $\mathbb{C}^4\setminus\{0\}$ does not descend to $M$.  In fact, the $(1,1)$-form on $\mathbb{C}^4\setminus\{0\}$ defined by $$\Omega = \frac{\sqrt{-1}}2\ \frac{{}^{t}\mathrm{d} z \wedge \mathrm{d}\bar z}{{}^tz\bar z}$$ is not closed, but, because it is invariant under scaling $z$, it descends to $M$ as a positive $(1,1)$-form that is *locally* a conformal multiple of a Kähler form, but it is not *globally* a conformal multiple of a Kähler form on $M$.  Thus, it is *locally* conformally Kähler.

Comment: Now I understood. Thank you very much.